# Modelling a basic sequential circuit as a transition system?

Tags: model-checking, software-verification, transition-systems

I'm going through Dr Joost-Pieter Katoen's slides and stumbled upon this:

[image]

For some reason I can't quite make out how the transition system relates to the sequential circuit. If I had a question for instance that asked me to convert the circuit into a TS, what steps should I take to approach it (using this one as an example).

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does the transition system (denoted by $\texttt{TS}$) relate to the sequential circuit (denoted by $\texttt{SC}$)?

- The states of $\texttt{TS}$ are all possible combinations of values of variable $x$ and register $r$ (*no output variable* $y$) in $\texttt{SC}$.
- The label of each state in $\texttt{TS}$ consists of all the variables (including the register) which are evaluated true given the valuations in $\texttt{SC}$.
  For example, $\{x, r, y \}$ for state $(x = 1, r = 1)$ means that all variables are true according to $\lambda_y = \lnot (x \oplus r)$ and $\delta_r = x \lor r$ given $x = 1, r = 1$.
- The transitions (arcs with arrow) between states in $\texttt{TS}$ result from the functions $\lambda_y$ and $\delta_r$.
  For example, $(x = 0,r = 1) \to (x = 0,r = 1)$ if the next input bit equals 0.

---

For more details and a general recipe for modeling sequential hardware circuits as transition systems, please refer to the book "Principles of Model Checking" (Section 2.1.2) by Christel Baier and Joost-Pieter Katoen. The MIT Press.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise 2.1. Consider the following two sequential hardware circuits:
r1
AND
x1
r2
OR
x2 OR AND
NOT
y1 y2
Questions:
(a) Give the transition systems of both hardware circuits.
(b) Determine the reachable part of the transition system of the synchronous product of these
transition systems. Assume that the initial values of the registers are r1=0 and r2=1.